# Program block avoiding race condition

Tags: system-verilog, testbench

I have a small design that assigns a value to a variable "addr" using initial block.

```
module design_ex(output bit [7:0] addr);
  
  initial begin
    addr <= 10; 
  end     
endmodule
```

Let's say I want to read this value in the testbench.

```
module tbench_top;
  wire [7:0] addr;
  
 
 

     design_ex dut(addr);
      
      initial begin
         //#1;
         $display("\t Addr = %0d",addr);
      end
```

This prints addr=0. But if I use a program block shown below, I get the correct value of address i.e addr=10.

```
program testbench(input bit [7:0] addr);
  initial begin
    $display("\t Addr = %0d",addr);
  end
endprogram


module tbench_top;
  wire [7:0] addr;
  
  //design instance
  design_ex dut(addr);
  
  //testbench instance
  testbench test(addr);

endmodule
```

How is it working in the case of program bloc? I know blocking assignments in program block are scheduled in the reactive region which is somewhat late in the simulation region. Is that the reason for program block fetching the correct value?

Comment: Used mentor questa in EDAPlayground

Answer (score 0):

Blocking assignments get scheduled in the region the process they are in execute. The only reason your `program` block sees the updated value of `addr` is that the `initial` block process is executing in the reactive region, which is after the NBA region of the module. If you used `$strobe` in your module's initial block, you would have gotten the same result.

The only race conditions a `program` blocks eliminate is when a blocking assignment is used in a module and then read in program block, you always get the updated value. It does not eliminate race conditions within a program block. I recommend [avoiding them altogether](https://blogs.sw.siemens.com/verificationhorizons/2009/05/07/programblocks/). There are many other ways to avoid race conditions between dut and testbench.